# Do we have place holder to automatically pass the default value of a parameter

Tags: c++

Let's say we have a function:

```
void foo (int a = 0, int b = 1);
```

Now I want to call `foo()` with some value for `b`. In this case I have to write down the default value for `a`, which may require me to look into the header file.

Is it possible to avoid it by passing some place holder which will automatically pass the default value (something like `auto`)?

Comment: ...aaand that's why default arguments aren't such a great feature after all.

Comment: you can create function: void fooWithDefaultA(int b){foo(0,b);}